# Can we fetch mails from inbuilt email app?

Tags: java, android, email

Is there any way fetch the mails from the inbuilt **Email app** that comes with the android device itself? Please note that I am **not referring** to the **Gmail app**. ??? If yes then please give a hint about it.
As per my research till now m not able to find any way to do this.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch the mails from the inbuilt Email app"? Also, what makes you think that all devices have the same "inbuilt Email app"?

Comment: Suppose that I have synced my yahoo mail on my device. I can view my mails on local email (just like MS Outlook on a desktop) both online and offline. what I want is that I want to fetch these mails and use in another application by giving username and password of that particular email Id like: example@yahoo.com , 123456.

Answer (score 0):

This would only be possible for applications that expose this data via some form of API. The Email application that is part of the Android open source project has no documented or supported API of this type.